# Upload to firebase do not work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Im trying to upload an image to firebase but it do not work.
This is my code:

```
var file = $("#fileUpload")

    var ref = firebase.storage().ref('img');

    ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    });
```

And this is the html code:

```
<li onClick={this.upload}>
    <a>
     <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
     <i className="fa fa-upload"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

This is the error givin:

> "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob
>   or File."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an HTML element to `StorageRef.put()`. It expects (as the error message says) a `Blob` or a `File`.

For an example how to upload from a web page, see the [documentation on uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files). I'd also recommend taking the [Firebase codelab for web](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/), which walks you through building a complete web chat app that includes uploading images.